# Can I blog adblock-enabled users from viewing content by wrapping content in an ad?

Tags: adblock

Just trying to find a good, simple way to block users who use adblock plus (ads are the only way writers can receive any money on our website, as with many sites).

It seems the plugins that block adblock-plus users can also be blocked.

I considered a simple solution. If their computers block ads, can't I just wrap my content in the ad, so they view all or nothing?

If not, can anyone think of any similar methods of denying users who want to deny any chance of compensation to the hardworking writers whose content they already enjoy without charge?

Possibly using a conditional statement dependent on the ad script?

Comment: Unfortunately for your business model, ad blocking is necessary for *security* while browsing the web nowadays - there have just been too many incidents of ad networks being abused to distribute malware; even the big names have failed to prevent this. Your only ethical option is to find your site a different source of funding.  (Note: if you violate [Yog's Law](http://whatever.scalzi.com/2014/06/20/yogs-law-and-self-publishing/) in the process, you have only moved the problem around.)

Comment: That is a totally ignorant comment, saying all online businesses that rely on advertising -- the only source of revenue for 99% of publishers throughout time on any medium -- need to stop because of "malware concerns." I've never had a malware problem, and I've never used adblocker, while using the internet over 12 hours every day, for several years. I use a simple free malware blocker. If users don't want to allow the sites they visit to earn money for their workers, they shouldn't visit those particular sites. But they won't be left with much, because no quality work will be available.

Comment: Sorry. The millions of users of the internet who *have* had a malware problem dispute your assertion. If sites that users visit want to stay in business, they need to learn to work with those users in regards to security, and if they don't want to they need to find another line of work. There are tons of sites with quality content that don't subject their users to forcible malware-vulnerable content. I personally have not been injured as a result of someone driving drunk, but that doesn't make driving drunk OK. Your defense is simply ignorant of the real world.

Comment: Even if I have a malware problem, I will not cut off the means by which the services I use stay in business. In saying "they need to find another line of work," you are totally disregarding all publishers on the internet, whose work you probably use every day. You are saying you will take what they provide, but you don't care if they receive anything for it, and actually you will keep them from a chance of receiving anything. Please name some publishing-based sites that stay in business without ads.

Comment: Sorry. You want your subscribers to pay, offer paid subscriptions. If they're that interested in your *quality content*, they'll pay for it.  Ad blockers allow control of the content of ads. If you choose to allow ads for kiddie porn, pirated software, or whatever else on your site, I don't have to accept it. Ad blockers have their place, and if you don't understand that you have no business selling internet content. This is the 21st century, and if you can't realize there's an issue with malware on the internet by now, you need to watch the news.

Comment: (continued). There's a difference between sites that *publish ads* (like this one) and sites that *force ads down your throat without the option to disable them* (like you intend). I can choose (at home) to accept ads from a site (like this one) unfiltered, a site (like some others) that have ads from content my work proxy doesn't like such as social networks, and block sites that have content that is useful but ads that are inappropriate or NSFW (like some Google search results for technical content). It's **my choice**, not yours, what ads I accept.

Comment: That's a joke. I don't want anyone to have to pay for online articles from our site. Your understanding of the ecosystem is limited. All it does is hurt those who produce the best quality things, and overall reduce those people. Some sites, like NYT try the subscription model. What happens is copywriters rip off their paid material (which costs NYT $60,000 a year for each writer, and it the reason those stories are brought to light) to make any amount they can. Your statement about no business selling internet content is just ignorant, and there isn't any needed argument.

Comment: Yes, its your choice. There's no argument. But by purposefully making it impossible for those sites (pretty much every internet site) to pay their workers, you are harming them and since there's a lot (and growing number) of you guys, it will cut off what allows those people to continue to produce things for you online. [This site, by the way, is not a publishing site -- it doesn't work on content, it benefits from what all its users add to it, so the staff that needs to be paid to keep it going must be quite small in relation to the content that the ads are displayed on]

Comment: You also don't seem to understand that the users of this site (which you use as an example) who allow the ads are the ones who overall pay for this site to continue. They pay for the site you use, while you exploit this system (if you disallow ads). The less of them there are, the less this site can continue. You are one of the ones (if you have ads disabled) who takes advantage of the fact other people are overall paying for the website you are using.

Comment: A passionate argument on both sides, but completely off-topic to the question at hand.  However, I think the question may be a bit too broad for this Q&A site.  You might try posting specific code that you need help with.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do that.

What you can do, however, (and this is a very popular technique) is put an image behind your ad telling your viewers about how ad-blocking is bad. That way, you can possibly persuade your viewers to disable their ad-block.

If your viewer has ad-block on, they'll be able to see the image. If they don't have ad-block on, the ad will overlap the image, so they'll only see the ad.

By doing that, at least you can convince sympathetic people to perhaps disable their ad-block.

Aside from that, you're really out of luck.

Comment: How about using css to provide two options. If ad is blocked, open enormous image (which blocks the page). If ads are enabled, show ad?

Comment: @Justin Munce People could easily just block your enormous image using an adblocker.